# Как сделать систему чекпоинтов в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при подборе чекпоинта сохранялось текущее состояние сцены, чтобы потом его можно было загрузить при смерти игрока. Допустим, если после подбора чекпоинта взрывается бомба, то при смерти игрока бомба становилась на прежнее место. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: А что при смерти обязательно надо сцену перезагружать, да еще и в определенном состоянии. А что просто перса вернуть на стартовую точку и скрипты перезапустить, не?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ прав. Вам надо четко определиться что вы хотите сохранять в сцене, а что нет.  Составьте список и для себя поймете, требуется ли перезагрузка сцены или надо только для отдельных объектов восстановить состояние.